# All @Resource injection before any @PostConstruct again

Tags: java, spring, resources, lifecycle, postconstruct

JSR-250 says all @Resource annotated methods will be called before the @PostConstruct method..

My question is:

Does that mean that all @Resource annotated methods on all beans in a context will be called before any @PostConstruct annotated methods are called?
Or in other words can a beans @PostConstruct method be called once its dependencies have been injected even if other beans in the context still haven't had there dependences injected?

Regards,
  Tim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is guaranteed that when a given bean's `@PostConstruct` gets called, that all of its `@Resource` fields will have been injected. If any of those injections are themselves beans with their own `@Resource` and `@PostConstruct`, then those will have already been called. In other words, by the time any given `@PostConstruct` is called, it is guaranteed that all of its dependencies have been fully initialized.

It is possible, and in fact likely, that `BeanA` will be constructed and initialized via `@PostConstruct` before `BeanB` has even been instantiated, *if* `BeanB` has no expressed dependency on `BeanA`.

Comment: Thanks Kenny :)  That explains it.